# Wrong users on question list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, users

The wrong user is displayed as the asker on the question list, the right one being shown on the question itself. This just happened moments ago...

[image: Question]

[image: List]

Comment: hah, sorry if I'm flooding the questions page, I just tend to do  maintenance in batches which bumps them all up to the hot list. We need to get a "ninja mod mode" or something.

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature, not a bug. The most recent user to post an answer or edit a question or answer shows up on the front page.

Unfortunately, I can't find the longer discussion of this on meta.SO to link to!

Comment: Well, it *does* say modified by ... x hours ago, but why is that behavior different on say webapps.stackexchange.com ?

For example, see this question in the list http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions#question-summary-4824
the asker's name is displayed, although it has been edited...
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/adding-equations-to-google-docs-presentation

Comment: @jfoucher: That I don't have an answer to. They may have made some change specific to the webapps site, but not having an interest in it, I haven't been paying attention to what they're doing there.

Answer (score 4):

I think I finally understood what is going on here.

For some reason, the behavior of the "Active" questions tab is diffferent than all the others : it shows the person who last responded/edited/commented on the question, whereas all the other tabs show the asker.

The reasons for this are understandable, in that if your are looking at active questions, you might as well show the last active user.